# SQL Server optimize query that have subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server and have a query with low performance. My query is like below:

```
Select * 
from ... 
Where exists (Select * From ... Where ...)
```

The execution time of above query is about 8 minute. if I use following format for this query, it run about 3 second.

```
declare @T table(Columns)
Insert into @T(columns)
Select *
From ...
Where ...

Select *
from ...
Where Exists (Select * From @T)
```

I can't use second format, because I use Entity Framework and it create query in first format. How can I do in order to have high performance with first query structure.

**Edit 1** I use Entity Framework 6

Also I can't use stored procedure, because I have a lots of parameters in order to filter my data in my application.

**Edit 2**
This is the actual query:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[MasterID] AS [MasterID], 
    [Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Project1].[DateOnly] AS [DateOnly], 
    [Project1].[SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID] AS [SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID], 
    [Project1].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Project1].[FormTypeID] AS [FormTypeID], 
    [Project1].[ProcessTypeID] AS [ProcessTypeID], 
    [Project1].[SalesCompanyID] AS [SalesCompanyID], 
    [Project1].[FinancialPeriodId] AS [FinancialPeriodId], 
    [Project1].[ParentMasterID] AS [ParentMasterID], 
    [Project1].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID], 
    [Project1].[RecievedDate] AS [RecievedDate], 
    [Project1].[SalesBranchID] AS [SalesBranchID], 
    [Project1].[SellerID] AS [SellerID], 
    [Project1].[IsCompanyIntercourse] AS [IsCompanyIntercourse], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [Project1].[C6] AS [C6], 
    [Project1].[C7] AS [C7], 
    [Project1].[C8] AS [C8], 
    [Project1].[C9] AS [C9], 
    [Project1].[C10] AS [C10]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[MasterID] AS [MasterID], 
        [Extent1].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID], 
        [Extent1].[RecievedDate] AS [RecievedDate], 
        [Extent1].[SalesBranchID] AS [SalesBranchID], 
        [Extent1].[SellerID] AS [SellerID], 
        [Extent1].[IsCompanyIntercourse] AS [IsCompanyIntercourse], 
        [Extent2].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Extent2].[DateOnly] AS [DateOnly], 
        [Extent2].[SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID] AS [SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID], 
        [Extent2].[Number] AS [Number], 
        [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description], 
        [Extent2].[FormTypeID] AS [FormTypeID], 
        [Extent2].[ProcessTypeID] AS [ProcessTypeID], 
        [Extent2].[SalesCompanyID] AS [SalesCompanyID], 
        [Extent2].[FinancialPeriodId] AS [FinancialPeriodId], 
        [Extent2].[ParentMasterID] AS [ParentMasterID], 
        '0X0X' AS [C1], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
        [Extent3].[FinancialPeriodID] AS [FinancialPeriodID1]
        FROM   [SAL].[Invoice] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [SAM].[Master] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[MasterID] = [Extent2].[MasterID]
        INNER JOIN [ORG].[SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID] = [Extent3].[SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID]
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE (10 = [Project1].[FinancialPeriodID1]) AND (13852 = [Project1].[SalesCompanyID]) AND ([Project1].[DateOnly] <= convert(datetime2, '2014-09-09 00:00:00.0000000', 121)) AND (convert(datetime2, '2014-09-07 00:00:00.0000000', 121) <=  CAST(  CAST( [Project1].[DateOnly] AS datetime2) AS datetime2)) AND (13852 = [Project1].[SalesCompanyID]) 
    AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent4].[OrderMasterID] AS [OrderMasterID], [Extent5].[MasterID] AS [MasterID1]
            FROM        [SAL].[InvoiceDetail] AS [Extent4]
            INNER JOIN [SAM].[Detail] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[DetailID] = [Extent5].[DetailID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [SAL].[Order] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent4].[OrderMasterID] = [Extent6].[MasterID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [SAL].[SalesBranch] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[SalesBranchID] = [Extent7].[SalesBranchID]
            INNER JOIN [SAL].[SalesBranch] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent6].[SalesBranchID] = [Extent8].[SalesBranchID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [SAL].[Order] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent4].[OrderMasterID] = [Extent9].[MasterID]
            INNER JOIN [SAL].[Order] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent4].[OrderMasterID] = [Extent10].[MasterID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [SAL].[Order] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent4].[OrderMasterID] = [Extent11].[MasterID]
            WHERE ([Extent7].[SalesScopeID] IN (43893, 43900)) AND ([Extent8].[SalesScopeID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent9].[SalesBranchID] IN (77017, 43063, 43029, 43021)) AND ([Extent10].[SalesBranchID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent11].[SellerID] IN (42768, 50552, 15904, 15090, 15717, 16063, 43109, 43110, 43113, 43114, 43118, 43120, 43121, 43123, 43124, 43125, 43126, 43127, 43129, 43130, 43131, 43132, 43133, 43134, 43136, 43137, 43138, 43141, 43147, 43152, 43153, 43154, 43160, 43168, 43178, 43179, 43184, 43185, 43186, 43187, 43189, 43209, 43211, 43215, 43218, 43223, 43235, 43242, 43248, 43249, 43250, 43251, 43252, 43261, 43269, 43278, 43283, 43298, 43308, 43313, 43316, 43325, 43328, 43329, 43337, 43356, 43360, 43384, 43385, 43394, 43400, 43415, 43418, 43424, 43425, 43428, 43434, 43441, 43518, 43532, 43546, 43548, 43549, 44359, 44368, 44490, 47035, 48849, 49139, 49140, 49153, 49156, 50212, 50422, 50423, 51023, 52158, 61908, 61909, 79146, 80261, 80466, 80734, 80735, 80983, 82822, 86309, 86436, 86578, 86825, 86879, 87120, 43149, 45166, 44366, 80233)) ) AS [Filter1]
        INNER JOIN [SAL].[Order] AS [Extent12] ON [Filter1].[OrderMasterID] = [Extent12].[MasterID]
        WHERE ([Extent12].[SellerID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Project1].[MasterID] = [Filter1].[MasterID1])
    )) AND ([Project1].[FormTypeID] = 6) AND (6 IS NOT NULL)
```

**Edit 3:** this is the execution plan of my query:

[image]

Comment: What version of entity framework?   You can write a stored procedure to do the second one and have entity framework reference the stored proc

Comment: Adding the actual where clause may be useful

Comment: @AlexK. the actual query is added.

Comment: Could you post your original .Net code who causes this query generation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQL Guru, but i think it's a very bad habit having subqueries; you should avoid this.

You can for example do your 2 subqueries first and dynamically build your final SQL query within the program. Or put some triggers on your tables on order to prepare the data for querying (create an easy-to-query extra table).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In first, I don't create dynamically query in my app, I use entity framework and it create query dynamically. And also I cant use table trigger, because trigger in sql server use for Insert/Update/Delete command, and not used for select query.

Comment: Well i'm an old timer, i'm not using frameworks as i prefer to keep control of what i do.. I know what can triggers do, i was telling that you can create triggers to populate a new table, expecially designed for your query.

Comment: @BenoitPHILIPPON Subqueries are there to be used. There's no bad in subqueries itself but only in bad statements (which can be built even with no subqueries).

Answer (score 0):

You may get better performance on the actual query if you check for missing indexes.  You can try running this in SQL Management Studio and use the Display Estimated Execution Plan, this will then show whether you are potentially missing indexes on the linked tables, if it does then by clicking on the messages you can generate the SQL Code to create the indexes.  Otherwise I think we may need to see the LINQ statement you are using to generate the said code.

Comment: I use `SQL Sentry plan explorer` in order to check execution plan of my query. this query don't have any missing indexes.

Comment: I edit my question and add execution plan of my query.

Comment: What about returning the them as separate lists and then determine your result set using exists on those lists rather than in one query?

Comment: I have large table in my database. in order to have better performance and save memory and network, we use paging in our application. and each page have only 50 record. in order to get external information of this 50 record entity framework use above query. and get only extended property of displayed record in the forms of my application.

Comment: is there no way of joining the tables from the exists clause into the main query?